# How to use shuffled List in for loop in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to clone an existing list, shuffle it and use it in a loop in a children. But when I use it I got an error.

If I use it like this:

```
const availablePlaycards = [
  Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'sheep.png'),
  Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'cow.png'),
  Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'pig.png'),
];
var doubledCards = (List.from(availablePlaycards)..addAll(clonedCards)).shuffle();
```

I got here

```
children: [
          for (final playcard in doubledCards)
```

the error:

```
A nullable expression can't be used as an iterator in a for-in loop.
and
This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
```

I have added an exclamation mark:

```
for (final playcard in doubledCards!)
```

But the error persists.

I have also tries like this without shuffle().

```
final List doubledCards = (List.from(availablePlaycards)..addAll(clonedCards));
```

Then I do not get the error, but the cards are not shuffled.

If I add shuffle here:

```
for (final playcard in doubledCards.shuffle())
```

I got the error:

```
A nullable expression can't be used as an iterator in a for-in loop.
```

How can I use it with shuffle?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to assign the return value of the [`shuffle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/shuffle.html) method, which is a `void`. You should use the [cascade notation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/shuffle.html) instead.

```dart
var doubledCards = List.from(availablePlaycards)..addAll(clonedCards)..shuffle();
```

Now `doubledCards` has a type of `List` so its value can be used as an iterator in a for-in loop.

This code is equivalent to:

```dart
var doubledCards = List.from(availablePlaycards);
doubledCards.addAll(clonedCards);
doubledCards.shuffle();
```